State Space Model with All Observed Factors
I have seen state space models implemented when we have latent/unobserved factors we want to uncover that jointly explain the dynamics of a time series of dependent variables. I have also seen state space models with a mix of observed and unobserved factors. Does it make sense to fit a state space model where all factors are observed? Meaning that I have a matrix X of data for the factors f_t and I want to fit a state space model where the factors follow an AR(1) process to then sample from the distribution of f_t+1 given f_t.

Fully observed state space model (SSM) as a smooth edge case of a typical SSM in fact is quite normal, think about the Hamiltonian formulation of classical mechanics whose states (position $q$, velocity or momentum $p$) are all observable.
If your transition model of the factors is AR(1) as $f_{t+1}=Af_t+ϵ_t$, you can fit your model by any suitable linear regression, MLE, or autocorrelation function (ACF) method. And your observation model is also simply $f_{t+1}=f_t+\eta_t$, where $ϵ_t,\eta_t$ usually represent Gaussian noises.
